# StaticArray efficient max size in Julia?

Tags: arrays, package, julia

What is the maximum efficient size of `StaticArray`?

I Mean if there exists size, when `StaticArray` is less efficient than ordinary `Array`?

And one more similar question. 
I should use `StaticArray` **every** time my array is not supposed to change it's size? Or there is any performance caveats?

Thx

Comment: Did you take a look at their [github page](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i found later, doc says:

> A very rough rule of thumb is that you should consider using a normal
>   Array for arrays larger than 100 elements. For example, the
>   performance crossover point for a matrix multiply microbenchmark seems
>   to be about 11x11 in julia 0.5 with default optimizations.

As mentioned chris-rackauckas, there is some issues with this "rule" in later julia versions. See https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl/issues/506

Comment: That's outdated though: https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl/issues/506